# Fuelphp Like logic with orm

Tags: php, orm, fuelphp, social-media-like

I have a small site where I would like to give the ability to users to like each profile with ajax.

So the logic is this, if the use clicks on the like it inserts, but if the person already liked and that's found in the database delete the record this would be the unlike function.

So the controller looks like this.

```
public function action_like()
{
    $response = Response::forge();
    $like = Model_Like::forge();
    $like->user_id = Input::post('user_id');
    $like->liked_by = Session::get('sentry_user');
    // find if the user already liked
    $row = Model_Like::find(array($like->user_id, $like->liked_by));
    //if liked remove from database
    if($row):
        $response->body(json_encode(array(
            'status' => 'no',
        )));
        $row->delete();
    else:
        $response->body(json_encode(array(
            'status' => 'yes',
        )));
        $like->save();
    endif;

    return $response;
}
```

javascript

```
$('button.like').on('click', function(){
    var likeId = $(this).data('like') 
    valPlus = parseInt($('.like-total').text()) + 1;;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: site_url + 'profile/like/',
        data: {user_id: likeId},
        dataType: "json",
        context: this,
        //async: false,
        beforeSend: function(data) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.debug(data);
            if(data.status == "yes") {

                $('.like-total').text(valPlus);
            }
        }, 
        complete: function(data) {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled', 'disabled');
        }
    })
});
```

So the problem is that the `$row` always retunrs `null`, so it is not locating the two id's and always inserts.

Could please someone give me a hint what I am missing?

Comment: How did you define `Model_Like`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have an error in your "Where". Can you try with this?

```
$row = Model_Like::find()->where(array(
    array('user_id', $like->user_id), 
    array('liked_id', $like->liked_by)
));
```

With your "Where" you where searching for the records with ids "$like->user_id" and "$like->liked_by", not for a single row with both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Seen a similar question today on here.

You can do

```
Model_Like::find_by_user_id_and_liked_id($like->user_id, $like->liked_by);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation: find() requires a primary key as parameter.

You can run a query by using the solutions mentioned by "Marco Pace" and "notrab". In the first case, use

```
Model_Like::query()
```

and not

```
Model_Like::find()
```

The last one just happens to work because not passing any parameters is an error situation in which the ORM's query object is returned because it doesn't know what to find. This behaviour might change in future versions.